# JLabel translation

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have a JLabel (with an icon) and I would like to translate this JLabel when the JLabel is clicked. I have added a mouseListener to the JLabel however I didn't come up with anything on how I can execute a translation from coordinates (x, y) to cordinates (x', y')

```
class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

        final JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
        System.out.println("Player hit label -> " + label.getName() );

        // Code for translating JLabel

    } 
}
```

Comment: You might want to check to make sure the e.getSource() returns a label before casting it

Comment: That's not the issue here anyway.

Comment: I know it's not the issue, that's why it's not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as translating (ie moving) your JLabel:

First, you must make sure that the layout manager of its parent is set to null, or uses a customized layoutmanager that can be configured to do your translation.

Once you have that in place, it's a simple matter:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ae) {
  JLabel src = (JLabel) ae.getSource();
  src.setLocation(src.getLocation().x + delta_x, src.getLocation().y + delta_y);
  src.getParent().repaint();
}
```